# How to enable gzip compression on Microsoft-IIS/8.0 with help of Web.config file

Tags: gzip, iis-8

How can I enable IIS8 to gzip static files like js and css and how can I test if IIS8 is really gziping them before sending to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First open chrome dev tools and go to network tab and check for static files size. After that you can enable gzip with

1. Open powershell as administrator and run the following command:
      Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server, Web-Dyn-Compression
2. Second option: Under Server Manager click Add roles and features
      -Click Next for Role-based or featured-based installation
      -Select Server Roles
      -Expand Web Server (IIS) role
      -Under Performance check the option for Dynamic Content Compression

after this you can check again static files

Comment: awesome advice. 1 line in powershell + gzip working! beats all those 7 page blog posts by a country mile